# PyXB randomly adds/removes xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"

Tags: pyxb

I have an issue where I create a xml string from a schema using PyXB and in some cases when the string is created the namespace xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" is added. When I recreate the string it is removed. How can it be that it sometimes adds the namespace and sometimes it is not adding it?

An example of how it looks when it is added

```
<ns1:Testdoc xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ns1="http://schema.test.com/time/1"><ns1:id>e1a1ba3a-8e5f-417c-8156-23ae80809522</ns1:id></ns1:Testdoc>
```

An example when it isn't added

```
<ns1:Testdoc xmlns:ns1="http://schema.test.com/time/1"><ns1:id>e1a1ba3a-8e5f-417c-8156-23ae80809522</ns1:id></ns1:Testdoc>
```

Comment: `xmlns` is the namespace that is used when the element has no prefix (`<prefix:SomeElement>` vs `<SomeElement>`). It is also inherited (of a higher element in the tree). Could you verify if a parent element has `xmlns` defined? And if not, could you show examples?

Comment: It is the parent element that sometimes includes it and sometimes not

Comment: `xmlns` isn't used in the snippet posted (there are no elements without prefix), so it doesn't matter if it's there or not. Whether why it's there or not, I don't know. I'll leave that answer to someone else.